# Problems loading certificates from main bundle

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I have some problems loading a certificate into an ios app (iOS 6.0 SDK), here is my code.

```
 NSData* certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xxx" ofType:@"crt"]];
      if( [certData length] ) {

          CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge CFDataRef)certData;

          SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData (kCFAllocatorDefault, myCertData);

          if( cert != NULL ) {
```

The certificate is always null, some one have any idea why??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the pathForResource: return? Is certData nil or only cert?

Comment: only cert, I successfully load the cert from the main bundle.